# The method 'getQuotes' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: getQuotes()

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and trying to parse JSON data from an API with this format:

---

```
[

  {

    "imageId": "5d30b60313fdf803e4db4500",
    "imageName": "chair",
    "imageUrl": "https://quotesst.blob.core.windows.net/myquotes/nature-4.jpg",
    "quote": "chair is good"
  },

  {

    "imageId": "5d8b1bcc1c9d4400000346f0",
    "imageName": "quote1",
    "imageUrl": "https://quotesst.blob.core.windows.net/myquotes/nature-4.jpg",
    "quote": "\"Success is not final; failure is not fatal: It is the courage to continue that counts.\" Winston S. Churchill"
  },

  {

    "imageId": "5d8b1c641c9d4400000346f1",
    "imageName": "quote2",
    "imageUrl": "https://quotesst.blob.core.windows.net/myquotes/nature-4.jpg",
    "quote": "“It is better to fail in originality than to succeed in imitation.” Herman Melville"
  }

]
```

---

and my flutter class is as follows:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

const url =
    'myapiurl';

class EnglishDatabase {
  Map<int, Map<String, String>> data = new Map();
  int dataLength = 0;
  List<String> temp;
  EnglishDatabase();

  void getData() async {
    Map<int, Map<String, String>> s;
    try {
      http.Response r = await http.get(url);
      if (r.statusCode == 200) {
        s = jsonDecode(r.body);
        data.addAll(s);
        dataLength = s.length;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void returnQuotes() async {
    await getData();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      temp.add(data[i]['quote']);
    }
  }

  Iterable<String> getQuotes() {
    returnQuotes();
    return temp.reversed;
  }

  int getQuotesLength() {
    return dataLength;
  }
}
```

and my class for calling this one to show the data is as follows:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quotes_flutter_stories/Database/EnglishQuoteData.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'Themes.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'main.dart';
//import 'package:quotes_flutter_stories/Database/EnglishQuoteData.dart';

EnglishDatabase _englishData;

class EnglishScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EnglishScreenState createState() => _EnglishScreenState();
}

class _EnglishScreenState extends State<EnglishScreen> {
  Iterable<String> englishQuotes;
  @override
  void initState() {
    englishQuotes = _englishData.getQuotes();
    super.initState();
  }

  List<String> englishStories = [
    '\"Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.\" \nAlbert Einstein',
    '\"Successful people do what unsuccessful people are not willing to do. Don\'t wish it were easier; wish you were better.\" \nJim Rohn',
    '\"I find that the harder I work; the more luck I seem to have.\" \nThomas Jefferson',
    '\"Don\'t be afraid to give up the good to go for the great.\" \nJohn D. Rockefeller',
    '\"Opportunities don\'t happen. You create them.\" \nChris Grosser',
    '\"It is better to fail in originality than to succeed in imitation.\" \nHerman Melville',
  ];

  Widget _buildRowQ(String englishQuote) {
    return new ListTile(
      leading: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        ),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        height: 30.0,
        width: 30.0,
        child: new Text(
          englishQuote.substring(1, 2),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      title: new Text(englishQuote),
      subtitle: new Divider(
        height: 20.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => QuotePage(englishQ: englishQuote)));
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRowF(String englishFavourite) {
    return new ListTile(
      leading: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        ),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        height: 30.0,
        width: 30.0,
        child: new Text(
          englishFavourite.substring(1, 2),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      title: new Text(englishFavourite),
      subtitle: new Divider(
        height: 20.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    FavouritePage(englishF: englishFavourite)));
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRowS(String englishQuote) {
    return new ListTile(
      leading: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        ),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        height: 30.0,
        width: 30.0,
        child: new Text(
          englishQuote.substring(1, 2),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      title: new Text(englishQuote),
      subtitle: new Divider(
        height: 20.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => StoryPage(englishS: englishQuote)));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> _menuitems = ["Change Language", "Rate US", "About Us"];
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: mainTheme,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Quotes & Stories'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              DropdownButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                items: _menuitems
                    .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(value),
                          value: value,
                        ))
                    .toList(),
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (value == _menuitems[0]) {
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => LanguageSelection()));
                    } else if (value == _menuitems[1]) {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RatePage()));
                    } else if (value == _menuitems[2]) {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => AboutUsPage()));
                    }
                  });
                },
                isExpanded: false,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20.0,
              ),
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  text: 'Quotes',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Favourites',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Stories',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              englishQuotes.isEmpty
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text('No Quotes'),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _englishData.getQuotesLength(),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return _buildRowQ(englishQuotes.elementAt(i));
                      },
                    ),
              favourites.isEmpty
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text('No Favourites'),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: favourites.length,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return _buildRowF(favourites[i]);
                      },
                    ),
              englishStories.isEmpty
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text('No Stories'),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: englishStories.length,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return _buildRowS(englishStories[i]);
                      },
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String englishS;
  StoryPage({Key key, @required this.englishS}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _StoryPageState createState() => _StoryPageState();
}

class _StoryPageState extends State<StoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String englishStory = widget.englishS;
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: mainTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('English Story')),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/1.jfif"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 250.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  englishStory,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 185.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: favourites.contains(englishStory)
                          ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
                          : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                      color:
                          favourites.contains(englishStory) ? Colors.red : null,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (favourites.contains(englishStory))
                            favourites.remove(englishStory);
                          else
                            favourites.add(englishStory);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await Share.share(englishStory);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 40.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Back'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuotePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String englishQ;
  QuotePage({Key key, @required this.englishQ}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _QuotePageState createState() => _QuotePageState();
}

class _QuotePageState extends State<QuotePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String englishQuote = widget.englishQ;
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: mainTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('English Quote')),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/1.jfif"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 250.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  englishQuote,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 185.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: favourites.contains(englishQuote)
                          ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
                          : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                      color:
                          favourites.contains(englishQuote) ? Colors.red : null,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (favourites.contains(englishQuote))
                            favourites.remove(englishQuote);
                          else
                            favourites.add(englishQuote);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                          await Share.share(englishQuote);
                        }
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 40.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Back'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FavouritePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String englishF;
  FavouritePage({Key key, @required this.englishF}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _FavouritePageState createState() => _FavouritePageState();
}

class _FavouritePageState extends State<FavouritePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String englishFavourite = widget.englishF;
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: mainTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('Favourite')),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/1.jfif"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 250.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  englishFavourite,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 185.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: favourites.contains(englishFavourite)
                          ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
                          : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                      color: favourites.contains(englishFavourite)
                          ? Colors.red
                          : null,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (favourites.contains(englishFavourite))
                            favourites.remove(englishFavourite);
                          else
                            favourites.add(englishFavourite);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await Share.share(englishFavourite);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 40.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Back'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

so if anyone can help me I would very much appreciate it.

NOTE: you can ignore the part of englishStories as it's just some other test. Thank You.

Comment: and where did you initialize `_englishData` ?

Comment: I did in the beginning of the class before entering the stateful widget and I tried calling the method of getQuotes in initstate() in the class as I searched online.
besides do I have to intialize it like this:
EnglishDatabase _englishData = new EnglishDatabase();
in order to work?

Comment: yes, you need to initialize it the way you mentioned.

Comment: @Selvin I tried intializing it in the beginning of the class but didn't work and I also called the method of _englishData in initState in beginning of EnglishScreen as I searched in the internet.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri I tried intialize it as I wrote but also same error. What else to do?

Comment: @Selvin Well after several tries and debugging I solved the problem and it was with list structure I had to initialize the list with dummy value in order to make it grow-able and accept its add function but, the thing is it takes too much to load the list and I have to open the first iteration of the list which is the dummy value I added and then get back only then the list will show. Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is like this:
you have to put a dummy value in the list if you want it to be grow-able other than that it will be fixed and you can't use its methods to add value as it will crash. Here is the flutter team documentation about this:

An indexable collection of objects with a length.

Subclasses of this class implement different kinds of lists. The most common kinds of lists are:

Fixed-length list. An error occurs when attempting to use operations that can change the length of the list.

Growable list. Full implementation of the API defined in this class.

The default growable list, as returned by new List() or [], keeps an internal buffer, and grows that buffer when necessary. This guarantees that a sequence of add operations will each execute in amortized constant time. Setting the length directly may take time proportional to the new length, and may change the internal capacity so that a following add operation will need to immediately increase the buffer capacity. Other list implementations may have different performance behavior.

The following code illustrates that some List implementations support only a subset of the API.

```
List<int> fixedLengthList = new List(5);
fixedLengthList.length = 0;  // Error
fixedLengthList.add(499);    // Error
fixedLengthList[0] = 87;
List<int> growableList = [1, 2];
growableList.length = 0;
growableList.add(499);
growableList[0] = 87;
```

Lists are Iterable. Iteration occurs over values in index order. Changing the values does not affect iteration, but changing the valid indices—that is, changing the list's length—between iteration steps causes a ConcurrentModificationError. This means that only growable lists can throw ConcurrentModificationError. If the length changes temporarily and is restored before continuing the iteration, the iterator does not detect it.

It is generally not allowed to modify the list's length (adding or removing elements) while an operation on the list is being performed, for example during a call to forEach or sort. Changing the list's length while it is being iterated, either by iterating it directly or through iterating an Iterable that is backed by the list, will break the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample Dart code which might help you.

```
class Dependent {
  void getData() async {
    print('reached');
  }
}

void main() {
  Dependent().getData();
}
```

Comment: Well after several tries and debugging I solved the problem and it was with list structure I had to initialize the list with dummy value in order to make it grow-able and accept its add function but, the thing is it takes too much to load the list and I have to open the first iteration of the list which is the dummy value I added and then get back only then the list will show. Can you help me with this issue?